# How correctly setup Stakeholders access in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I want to setup for users who do not have CAL licence for TFS Stakeholders license type.Partially I did it by grant them Stakeholders access in Admin section. but I  do not know which "security" group they should be members.
What type of permissions should they have ? 
I did not found security group like Stakeholders.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what permission you'd like to grant to these stakeholders. Different teams have different requirement, so there is no stakeholder group by default. But you can create a group for them and configure the security for this group base on your team requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be mixing up TFS access levels versus project security.

Read about them here:

- [Access Levels](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels)
- [Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252512(v=vs.90).aspx)

Generally, you would give users either Stakeholder or Basic access, then add them to the Contributors, Readers, or Project Administrators groups. It depends on what you want them to be able to do. Stakeholder + Contributor or Reader is pretty common.

Here is a link describing [permissions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions).

Comment: No. I know what is access level and i Know what is Security.
 'Stakeholder + Contributor or Reader is pretty common.'  is what i wanted to know. Because for me Contributor have to many rights and Reader oposit. So i think i have to creat new group depending on Readers and grant few more rights.

Comment: Yes, you can create a new group through <collection uri>/<project>/_admin/_security and assign whatever rights you like. However, keep in mind that all security is not centrally located. For example, Source Control security is in a different place than Area Node (classification) security.

Comment: I also know this as i said i did not know what security group should i use for stakeholders. Source code is not visible in stakeholders acces so i do not need change these rights. Thanks ;)

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question, or it's too general.

Comment: Hm i do not know correctly how to explain.. generally you answered what i wanted to know: "stakeholders + contributors"  but this is not good for me , stakeholders + readers are not goog for me ... but it is correct answer. As i said i did not know what securtty group should i use for stakeholder and you answered. What for me is not solution so i will create new security group ;)

Comment: What do you want Stakeholders to be able to do?

Comment: Just create and edit their own work items (backlog or story  and bugs )

Comment: This is generally what a project's Contributor group is for. If you don't want them to have the other perms a contributor has, then you can either reduce the permissions for Contributor, or you can create a new group. The new group should have at least "View project-level information" (to see the project) and "View/Edit work items in this node" (set in Areas Security). I have added a link that describes TFS permissions to my answer.

Comment: The questions is about the license and how to be conform to it because the documentation from Microsoft says something about the "Stakeholder" access level and you can select it when in Azure but not in TFS2013 and TFS2015 contrary to the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops&tabs=stakeholder